# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \large\frac{k}{\text{e}^{2\pi k}-1}=\frac{1}{24}-\frac{1}{8\pi}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{\text{e}^{2\pi k}-1}=\frac{1}{24}-\frac{1}{8\pi}$$

Comment: $\large\frac{2\pi k}{\text{e}^{2\pi k}-1}=k\pi (\coth(k\pi)-1)$

Comment: I can transform the sum to $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{m+1} \mathrm{csch}^2{(\pi m)}$.  Unfortunately, I have to get back to work.  I will come back if nobody has solved by then.

Comment: @Chris'ssister Have you tried using the Laplace transform as a tool to find the limit of this series using this paper? See http://mathdl.maa.org/images/cms_upload/A_Laplace_Transform18380.pdf.

Comment: @Elias: Thank you for that link I find it interesting. I'm going through it right now.

Comment: Interestingly, if one _blindly_ applies the Plana summation formula$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k) = -\frac{1}{2} f(0) + \int_0^\infty f(t) \mathrm{d}t + \int_0^\infty i \frac{f(i t)-f(-i t)}{\\exp(2 \pi t)-1} \mathrm{d}t$$ although it is not applicable because $f(t)$ is not bounded in the right half complex plane, one gets $\frac{1}{12} - \frac{1}{4 \pi}$ which twice the exact answer. This hints that the sum may be amendable to complex analysis techniques. Here $f(k)$ refers to the summand.

Comment: @user40314: interesting point (+1). I also like to apply formulas where the requirements are not met, and surprisingly sometimes I get interesting results as yours.

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392706/evaluating-sum-n-1-infty-fracne2-pi-n-1-using-the-inverse-melli

Comment: @Argon once again, complex analisys is proving to be a very powerful tool.

Comment: @user40314 When $\large\Re\left(t\right) \gg 1$ we'll have $\large\left\vert{\rm f}\left(t\right)\right\vert \sim 2\pi \left\vert t\right\vert\exp\left(-2\pi\Re\left(t\right)\right)$. So, I didn't understand your point.

Comment: @user40314 I checked your Abel-Plana is half-etc as you said. By checking the Wikipedia entry the function will not satisfy the condition "$\large\ C/\left\vert z\right\vert^{1 + \epsilon}\ $" they impose on $\large{\rm f}\left(t\right)$.

Comment: It is amusing since,  "essentially", the sum is the energy of a photon gas with discrete wave numbers. I guess @Fabian answer exploits this fact.

Comment: i found a proof of the stated $1/\sinh(πn)^2$
sum using only basic contour integration. in case someone is interested i can post it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rewrite
$$\frac{1}{e^{2\pi k} -1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2\pi k n}.$$

So we need to evaluate
$$\sum_{n,k=1}^\infty k e^{-2\pi k n}.$$

Summing first over $k$, we have
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty k e^{-2\pi k n} = \frac1{2\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial n} \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-2\pi k n} = \frac1{2\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial n} \frac{1}{e^{2\pi n} -1} =\frac{e^{2\pi n}}{(e^{2\pi n}-1)^2} = \frac{1}{4 \sinh^2(\pi n)} .$$

The sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sinh^2(\pi n)} =\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{2\pi} $$ is evaluated [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicCosecant.html), see also page 3 [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/venkalatex.pdf), and the quoted result follows.

Comment: beautiful answer!

Comment: Better yet, here's a link to the paper in which the result is derived.  http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/venkalatex.pdf

Comment: @nbubis: thanks, I was trying to evaluate $\sum_n \text{csch}^2 (\pi n)$ from first principles but it seems not so easy. The second reference needs two pages to prove it (ok, he has a more general result).

Comment: @fabian: apologies, didn't see that.  Very nontrivial exercise indeed.

Comment: @Fabian: Thank you for the nice approach offered! (+1)

Comment: Interesting -- I did the same manipulation with the sums and the derivative, then found that Wolfram|Alpha has more difficulty with [the transformed sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+exp+%282+pi+n%29+%2F+%28exp+%282+pi+n%29+-+1%29^2+for+n%3D1..infinity) than with [the original one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+k+%2F+%28exp+%282+pi+k%29+-+1%29+for+k%3D1..infinity), and wrongly concluded that the transformation had led me away from a solution :-)

Comment: @joriki: you should have tried the [equivalent sum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+1%2Fsinh%28n+pi%29%5E2+for+n%3D1..infinity) which it has obviously tabulated :-)

Comment: I wonder if there is a faster/simpler way to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sinh^2(\pi n)} =\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{2\pi}$.

Comment: @Chris'ssister: I wondered a long time myself (tried it very hard). However, the statement `which was evidently first proved by T. S. Nanjundiah [11] in 1951` in the paper made me decide that there is none.

Comment: +1. Fine answer. It looks like a photon gas with discrete wave numbers.

Comment: i found a proof of the stated $1/\sinh(\pi n)^2$ sum using only basic contour  integration. in case someone is interested i can post it.

Comment: @tired: I am interested, you could add it as an additional (complementary) answer to this question.

Comment: @Fabian i think my approach is straighforwardly expandable to proof the general result stated in the paper by Berndt et al. linked above, so i will try to this in the (european) evening and then post what i get

Comment: @Fabian done! that was fun :)

Answer (score 8):

Consider the function complex valued function

> $$f(z)=\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{\sinh^2(z \pi)}$$

and integrate it along a quadratic contour $\mathcal{C}$ with verticies $\{( N/2,i N/2),(- N/2,i N/2),(- N/2,-i N/2),( N/2,-i N/2)\}$ where  $N$ is a (big) odd natural number. Note that the choice of such of kind verticies is necessary to bypass the poles  of $f(z)$.

The result is (we travel counter-clockwise)

$$
\oint_{\mathcal{C}}f(z)dz=\int_{N/2}^{-N/2}dxf(x+i N/2)+i\int_{N/2}^{-N/2}dyf(i y+ N/2)+\\\int_{-N/2}^{N/2}dxf(x-i N/2)+i\int_{-N/2}^{N/2}dyf(i y+ N/2)
$$

we now have (this is an exercise for the reader)

$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}f(x\pm i N/2)=\frac{\mp i}{\cosh^2(\pi x)}$ and that $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}f(i y\pm N/2)=0$.

Furthermore it is elementary to show (the integrand is the derivative of $\tanh$) that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\cosh^2(\pi x)}dx=\frac{2}{\pi}$
which means that

$$
\oint_{\mathcal{C}}f(z)dz=-2\frac{2i}{\pi}+2\cdot0=-\frac{4i}{\pi} \quad (\spadesuit)
$$

in the limit $N\rightarrow \infty$.
On the other hand we know by the residue theorem that (note that $(N-1)/2$ is an integer by construction)

$$
\oint_{\mathcal{C}}f(z)dz=2 \pi i\sum_{-(N-1)/2\leq k\leq (N-1)/2}\text{Res}(f(z),z=k)+\text{Res}(f(z),z=i k)
$$

it is now straightforward to show that

$$
\text{Res}(f(z),z=k)=\text{Res}(f(z),z=i k) = \frac{1}{\pi\sinh^2(\pi k)} \quad \text{if}\,\,k\neq0
$$

$$
\text{Res}(f(z),z=0) =-\frac{2}{3 \pi}
$$

which allows us to write that

$$
\oint_{\mathcal{C}} f(z)dz = 8 i\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sinh^2(\pi k)}-\frac{4 i}{3} \quad (\heartsuit)
$$

In the limit of $N\rightarrow\infty$.

Now putting togehter $(\heartsuit)$ and $(\spadesuit)$ it follows that

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sinh^2(\pi k)}=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{2\pi} \quad\blacksquare
> $$

this proves the result used by @Fabian

---

*Appendix*

if we set $f_a(z)=\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{\sinh^2(a z \pi)}$ and follow the same steps as above we can show that on the one hand the sum of residues equals

$$
\oint_{\mathcal{C}} f_a(z)dz=4i\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{\sinh^2(k \pi a)}+\frac{4i}{a^2}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{\sinh^2(k \pi/ a)}-\frac {2 i}{3}\frac{1+a^2}{a^2}\quad (\heartsuit \heartsuit)
$$

and on the other hand, by parametrizing the contour of integration as shown above, we get that
$$
\oint_{\mathcal{C}} f_a(z)dz=-\frac{4i}{\pi a} \quad (\spadesuit \spadesuit)
$$

Now putting togehter $(\heartsuit\heartsuit)$ and $(\spadesuit\spadesuit)$ it follows that

> $$
> \sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{\sinh^2(k \pi a)}+\frac{1}{a^2}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{\sinh^2(k \pi/ a)}=\frac{1+a^2}{6 a^2}-\frac{1}{\pi a}\quad\blacksquare\quad\blacksquare
> $$

in accordance with [Berndt et al.](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/venkalatex.pdf)

Comment: @r9m thanks, that is very kind of you

Comment: It is interesting to prove that some parts of the contour don't vanish.

Comment: Nice answer. For some reasons I simply missed this post.

Comment: $+1$. Wow !!!.${}{}{}{}{}$.

Answer (score 6):

If we define Dedekind eta function $\eta(q)$ via the equation $$\eta(q) = q^{1/12}\prod_{i = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{2i})\tag{1}$$ then it can be proved via functional equation of Dedekind eta function that $$n^{1/4}\eta(e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}}) = \eta(e^{-\pi/\sqrt{n}})\tag{2}$$ Let's define function $P(q)$ as $$P(q) = 1 - 24\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\frac{iq^{2i}}{1 - q^{2i}} = 12q\frac{d}{dq}\log\eta(q)\tag{3}$$ Logarithmic differentiation of equation $(2)$ with respect to $n$ gives us $$nP(e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}}) + P(e^{-\pi/\sqrt{n}}) = \frac{6\sqrt{n}}{\pi}\tag{4}$$ and putting $n = 1$ we get $$P(e^{-\pi}) = \frac{3}{\pi}\tag{5}$$ and looking at the definition of $P(q)$ we see that the above equation is exactly what is asked in the question.

Comment: this made short work of it  (+1)

Comment: @tired: Ramanujan dealt with such sums of hyperbolic functions in great detail and I learnt most of his technique from his collected papers. The beauty of his approach is the use of elementary tools (algebra and calculus of single real variable) and it shows that these basic tools (available to any high schooler) can prove very deep results.

Comment: it is somehow logical that Ramanujan chosed this appproach because his lack of a formal mathematical education (as Euler did in a time where formal mathematics wasn't developed). And it is absolutely incredible how far he came...

Comment: @tired : fully agree. By the way in case you have not noticed the last equation in your answer dealing with variable $a$ is same as the equation $(4)$ of my answer (just put $a=\sqrt{n} $).

Comment: yes indeed. calculating this sum is equivalent to show the functional equation for the $\eta$-function. Btw. do you know how to calculate the sum for higher powers of $\sinh(\pi x)$. Residue theory doesn't seem enough to do this :/

Comment: @tired: there are identities to handle the powers of hyperbolic functions also. I will extract some info and post after sometime.

Comment: @tired: sorry there do not appear identities like that. I was thinking more of identities related to sums like $\sum k^{a} /\sinh k\pi$ for integers $a$

Comment: i found a paper which evaluates such sums as special cases  of more general formulas, but it is insane: https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0198

Comment: @ParamanandSingh How does one prove the functional equation $(2)$?

Comment: @Nilknarf : this is a consequence of the transformation formula for Jacobi theta functions.