# Generating function for the divisor function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, generating-functions

Earlier today [on MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html) (see eq. 17)  I ran across the following expression, which gives a generating function for the divisor function $\sigma_k(n)$: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sigma_k (n) x^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^k x^n}{1-x^n}. \tag{1}$$

(The divisor function $\sigma_k(n)$ is defined by $\sigma_k(n) = \sum_{d|n} d^k$.)

> How would one go about proving Equation (1)?

(For reference, I ran across this while thinking about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272909/prove-that-sum-k-1-infty-large-frack-texte2-pi-k-1-frac124) asked earlier today.  The sum in that question is a special case of the sum on the right side of Equation (1) above.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Switching the order of summation, we have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma_{k}(n)x^{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n}\sum_{d|n}d^{k}=\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}d^{k}\sum_{n:\ d|n}^{\infty}x^{n}.$$ From here, applying the formula for the [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), we find that the above equals  $$\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}d^{k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{nd}=\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}d^{k}\frac{x^{d}}{1-x^{d}}.$$

Such a generating series is known as a [Lambert Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series).  The same argument above proves that for a multiplicative function $f$ with $f=1*g$ where $*$ represents [Dirichlet convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution), we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)x^n =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{g(k)x^k}{1-x^k}.$$

Comment: I don't think $f$ and $g$ even have to be multiplicative for that identity to hold.

Comment: Wait but isn't $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{nd} = \frac{1}{1-x^d}$?

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{nd} =\frac{1}{1-x^{d}} \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{nd} =\frac{x^d}{1-x^{d}} $$