# A bridge between the sum of the divisors and the Totient function

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, totient-function, divisor-sum

Let's consider:  $$\tau(x,a,b)=\sum_{1 \le d \le x \\ (d,x)=d^a \\} d^b$$

Where $(q,r)$ denotes the gcd of $q$ and $r$.

I think this could be interesting thing to look at because it's somehow a type of bridge between the sum of the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) $\sigma_k(x)=\tau(x,1,k)$ and [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\phi(x)=\tau(x,0,0)$.

Now, the [average order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_order_of_an_arithmetic_function#Divisor_functions) of these functions is fairly well understood.

For [example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iuzwyluesc),

$$\sum_{n=1}^x \tau(n,1,1) \approx \frac{\pi^2}{12}x^2$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^x \tau(n,0,1) \approx \frac{1}{\pi^2}x^3$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^x \tau(n,1,0) \approx x\log(x)+(2\gamma+1)x$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^x \tau(n,0,0) \approx \frac{3}{\pi^2}x^2$$

And these can be argued using the standard techniques which are [Abel Summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) and [Dirichlet convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution). Where $\gamma$ is the [Euler Macheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Is it possible to achieve similar results for non integer values $a$?

> For example, what is the average order of $\tau(x,\frac{1}{2},1)$? What is the average order $\tau(x,\frac{1}{2},0)$?

Comment: [Here's](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/usdfxaayvh) the first 100 values of the functions.

Comment: I just chose $\tau$ because it's in between $\sigma$ and $\phi$ in the Greek alphabet. It shouldn't be confused with $\tau$ as $\sigma_0$ which is sometimes how it used in number theory. If this is confusing to anyone I guess I could change it to an upsilon.

Comment: Why asking for the asymptotic of many weird arithmetic functions instead of studying the famous ones (in particular the prime number theorem) ? Here and to all your questions the methods of the PNT and the Dirichlet divisor problem (poles and bounds for the Dirichlet series, Mellin inversion, tauberian theorem) apply.

Comment: @reuns. Undoubtedly, I should study the classics. But I think $\tau$ is interesting in that is a type of bridge between important functions.

Comment: Then can you at least define the Dirichlet series corresponding to your question and why there is a chance we can find the asymptotic of the partial sums of their coefficients

Comment: like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273275/generating-function-for-the-divisor-function)

Comment: The generating functions for $\sigma_k$ and $\phi$ are presented in the wiki on [Lambert Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series)

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204095/residue-for-the-generating-function-of-the-euler-totient-function) also seems relevant

Comment: It looks like we can (sometimes) move from LG to DGFs according to this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Dirichlet_series_generating_functions_(DGFs)).

Comment: Since $\sum_{d | n}\phi(d)=n $ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi(n) n^{-s}= \frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}$. The Riemann zeta function has a lot of nice properties from which we can say a lot on  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi(n) n^{-s}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N \phi(n)$. Can you do the same with your above functions ?

Comment: I dunno but I can try

Comment: $\tau$ (or from my other question $\phi_k$) isn't multiplicative so I'm not sure that this approach is going to work for a non-multiplicative function.