# Where does the second '1' appear?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Where does the second '1' appear in a value of following series?

$\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{99}+\frac{1}{999}+\dots$=$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{1}{10^n-1}}$

I already have a value of

[Value of $x=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{1}{10^n-1}} $ and location of second digit $1$ of $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788573/sum-n-1-infty-frac110n-1) (link)

But I want to know where the second '1' appears without this result.

There is easy way to determine poistion of the second '1'?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{9}+\frac{\color{red}{1}}{99}+\frac{1}{999}+\dots$$

Comment: See this [problem](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/an-interesting-series/?group=FQQy11KrwYwQ&ref;_id=166193).

Comment: Why did you accept (25 minutes after the question was asked) an answer which does not (as far as I can see) answer the question? That is, except if a complete solution is behind the wall where Brilliant asks to register...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The decimal representation of $\frac{1}{10^n-1}$ has a one in every position that is a multiple of $n$.

For more details, read this [problem](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/an-interesting-series/?group=FQQy11KrwYwQ&ref;_id=166193). If you want more problems on this series, look at [this](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/ill-carry-you-home/?group=Tioo9AmkWPx1) and [this](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/an-interesting-series/?group=FQQy11KrwYwQ&ref;_id=166193).

Answer (score 1):

Due to the ways the 1's are regularly repeated in the summation, the $n^{th}$ digit will, up to a certain point, equal the number of divisors of $n$. This will break down when the number of divisors exceeds 10.

Since every number > 1 has at least 2 divisors (itself and 1) we will not encounter another 1 until after the breakdown point.

A 1 will appear when we either reach a number with 10 divisors followed by a number with between 10 and 19 divisors.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_divisors , 944 has 10 divisors, and 945 16 divisors, so the 944th digit will be a 1.

Comment: But 576 is smaller.