# How to evaluate a Lambert-type series in finite terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, modular-forms, elliptic-functions

Consider
$$\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{mx^m}{1 - x^{2m}}.$$
Does anyone know how to evaluate these Lambert-type series in finite terms? The right-hand side is related to
$$\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{x^m}{1 - x^{2m}} = L(x) - L(x^2),$$
where
$$L(x) = \sum_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{x^m}{1 - x^m}.$$
I know a related series
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{q^n}{1 + q^n}$$
can be expressed in terms of the Jacobi theta function $\vartheta_3(q)$ as
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{q^n}{1 + q^{2n}} = \frac{\vartheta_3(q)^2 - 1}{4},$$
but I cannot figure out how to relate the series in question to anything known to express it in finite terms so to speak. I am aware that $L(x)$ can be expressed in terms of the $q$-Polygamma function, but I do not think it can be expressed in finite terms.

Answer (score 3):

The Lambert series $$A(x) := \sum_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{mx^m}{1 - x^{2m}}$$ is the generating function of sequence [A002131](http://oeis.org/A002131). See the OEIS link for more information. One formula similar to your $L(x)$ formula is
$$A(x) = (P(x^2) - P(x))/24$$ where $P(x)$ is a Ramanujan Eisenstein-Lambert series, the generating function of sequence [A006352](http://oeis.org/A006352).
I know of several other expressions but this should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

The function, say $f(x) $, of your question is connected to Ramanujan's $P$ function given by $$P(q) =1-24\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{iq^{i}} {1-q^{i}}\tag{1}$$ via $f(q) =(P(q^{2})-P(q))/24$. If $0<q<1$ then the above can be evaluated in terms of theta functions and elliptic integrals. Thus using Jacobi's theta functions $$\vartheta_{2}(q)=2q^{1/4}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}q^{i(i+1)},\vartheta_{3}(q)=1+2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}q^{i^{2}}\tag{2}$$ we get the modulus $k$ and the complete elliptic integrals $K(k) , E(k)$ as $$k=\frac{\vartheta_{2}^{2}(q)}{\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q)}, K(k) =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\sin^{2}x}} = \frac{\pi} {2}\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q),\notag\\ E(k) =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-k^{2}\sin^{2}x}\,dx\tag{3}$$ and [we have the following formulas](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/05/certain-lambert-series-identities-and-their-proof-via-trigonometry-part-2.html):
\begin{align} 
P(q) & =\left(\frac{2K(k)}{\pi}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{6E(k)}{K(k)}+k^{2}-5\right)\tag{4}\\
P(-q) & =\left(\frac{2K(k)}{\pi}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{6E(k)}{K(k)}+4k^{2}-5\right)\tag{5}\\
P(q^{2})&=\left(\frac{2K(k)}{\pi}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{3E(k)}{K(k)}+k^{2}-2\right) \tag{6}
\end{align}

There are efficient algorithms to evaluate $K(k), E(k) $ from the value of $k$ using arithmetic-geometric mean. I don't think there are any closed forms which don't involve theta functions / elliptic integrals.

---

**Update**: BTW Ramanujan proved that if $q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}} $ where $n$ is a positive rational number then $$P(q) +\frac{6}{\log q} =\left(\frac{2K(k)}{\pi}\right)^{2}\cdot A(n)\tag{7} $$ where $A(n) $ is an algebraic number dependent on rational number $n$. And further if $n$ is a perfect square then $K(k) $ can be expressed in terms of $\Gamma (1/4), \pi$ and certain algebraic numbers. Thus the function in your question has a finite closed form in terms of $\pi, \Gamma(1/4)$ and certain algebraic numbers for a range of special values of $q$. However, this is easier said than done and it is very difficult to evaluate the desired algebraic numbers. Ramanujan  was a master of such calculations and modern approach to such calculations is based on software like Maple, Mathematica and Macsyma.

**Further Update**: S. Chowla and A. Selberg proved that the elliptic integrals $K, E$ can be expressed in closed form using Gamma values and $\pi$ if $n$ is a positive rational. This result appears to be harder to establish than all the results mentioned above in my answer. Thus for all values of $q$ of the form $q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}}$ with $n$ a positive rational your sum has a closed form in terms of Gamma values, $\pi$ and certain algebraic numbers.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ultimately, this approach boils down to evaluating $E(k)$ because there are known methods of evaluating $K(k)$. Evaluating $E(k)$ is trickier. In fact, this is where my question comes from: the series in question relates $K(k)$ and $E(k)$. Alternatively, the problem boils down to evaluating $E_2(\tau)$ because it is expressible in terms of $K(k)$ and $E(k)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Do you know of any systematic methods of evaluating $E(k)$ or $E_2(\tau)$? I know some values of the elliptic $\alpha$ function (which links $K(k)$ and $E(k)$) are known and can be found in Borwein's book, but are there more elegant ways?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh How do you relate $P(x)=1-24\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{mx^m}{1 - x^{m}}$ with $A(x)=\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{mx^m}{1 - x^{2m}}$ ?..

Comment: @user1952009 : $A(x) =(P(x^{2})-P(x))/24$ because $$\frac{mx^{2m}}{1-x^{2m}}-\frac{mx^{m}}{1-x^{m}}=-\frac{mx^{m}}{1-x^{2m}}$$

Comment: @glebovg: the evaluation of $E$ is somewhat difficult compared to $K$ but based on arithmetic-geometric-mean. You can see my blog post http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/pi-and-the-agm-evaluating-elliptic-integrals-contd.html for more details. You will also need to read the previous post http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/pi-and-the-agm-evaluating-elliptic-integrals.html to get used to the notation.

Comment: Right I missed that. So the OP's function is related with the "elementary" (quasi) modular forms and theta functions. Then why are you bothering with $K,k$ ? For $|x| \le r < 1$ all those series converge fast enough to evaluate them numerically, accelerating isn't really the problem. And for $|x|$ very close to $1$ we should be able to exploit the modularity

Comment: @user1952009 : you should see my updated section  at the end. If numerical evaluation was the only thing of importance related to any series then infinite series would have been pretty uninteresting. It is the link between various series and functions which makes them enjoyable. The elliptics and thetas led to my blogging and even after so many years I am still amazed by their interplay. Unfortunately this beautiful theory has been totally destroyed by the modern modular form approach which sort of heavily relies on machine computation.

Comment: We can deduce many properties for the OP's function from its expression in term of elliptic and modular functions, which is the beautiful theory you are referring to, right ? And for most people $K(k), E(k), k(q)$ are obscure functions, that's why I don't get why you want to mention them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62055/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-user1952009).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I do not think Chowla and Selberg proved anything about $E(k)$. Do you know of any papers or books other than Borwein's book, where $E(k)$ or $E_2(\tau)$ is systematically evaluated for some values of $k$ or $\tau$?

Comment: @glebovg: once you know $K$ can be evaluated in closed form using Gamma values and $\pi$ for all singular moduli $k$ then from Ramanujan's theorem mentioned in equation $(7)$ above $P(q) $ has a similar closed form. And then from equation $(4)$ which links $P, K, E$ one can see that $E$ has a similar form. I have not read the paper from Chowla (because I don't know much about the theory used in that paper), but it may be that they didn't mention about $E$ specifically because it is obvious from the relations between $P, K, E$ for singular moduli.

Comment: @glebovg: the simplest evaluation of $E$ is for $E(1/\sqrt{2})$ for $q=e^{-\pi}$. Here we know that $$K=\frac{\Gamma^{2}(1/4)}{4\sqrt{\pi}}, P(q^{2})=\frac{3}{\pi}$$ and then from $(6)$ we get $$E(k) =\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{\Gamma ^{2}(1/4)}+\frac{\Gamma^{2}(1/4)}{8\sqrt{\pi}}$$

Comment: @glebovg : the fact $P(q^{2})=3/\pi$ for $q=e^{-\pi} $ is proved in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2285656/72031